# Firebase: get lisg when app wad closed (AngularFireDatabase + Angular 4)

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have and app on m device. If the app was opened, all run correctly. But when I closed the app, this methon don't run

```
this.db.list('/chats/' + uid).subscribe(data => {
            alert("Hellow");
            return data;
        });
```

I need this method to run even though the application was closed, because I want to launch an alert when the list changes

I'm using fot this AngularFireDatabase, angular 4 and ionic.

Sorry for m english, regards

Answer (score 0):

Use Push Notifications from Firebase.
[Read how it works](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/send-push-notifications-in-angular-with-firebase-cloud-messaging/)

Answer (score 0):

use [ionic native background mode](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode/)  this will not allow your app to go to sleep

Comment: Dissapear on 2018